# How can I speed up the performance Spring Jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, performance, jpa, query-optimization

The code

```
        int offset = 0;
        int bulkSize = eodFileConfig.getBulkSize(); // sample of 10k
        setDateTimeFormat();

        //Get total record from Temp table
        long max = extQRMerchantTrxHistService.getTotalRecords();


        do {
            log.debug("[execute] start to write to actual table");
            // bulk size represent how many items in a page, offset is the page
            Page<ExtensionQRMerchantTrxHistEntity> records = extQRMerchantTrxHistService.findRecordsWithPagination(offset, bulkSize);
            List<TransactionHistoryExtEntity> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

            for (ExtensionQRMerchantTrxHistEntity tempEntity : records) {
                log.debug("Record: {} ", tempEntity);
                Date a = new Date();
                //Query from T_TRXN_DETAIL_EXT
                Date dateTime = sf.parse(tempEntity.getTransactionDate());
                List<TransactionHistoryExtEntity> histories =
                        transactionHistoryInquiryService.retrieveHistoryBasedOnRefNoDateAmt(
                                tempEntity.getTransactionRefNo(), dateTime, tempEntity.getTransactionAmount());
                Date b = new Date();
                System.out.println("Query Time: " + Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime()));
                Date c = new Date();
                TransactionHistoryExtEntity transaction;
                if (histories.isEmpty()) {
                    //Insert record
                    transaction = setTransactionHistory(Boolean.TRUE, tempEntity, null);
                } else {
                    //Update record
                    transaction = setTransactionHistory(Boolean.FALSE, tempEntity, histories.get(0));
                }
                Date d = new Date();
                System.out.println("Query Time: " + Math.abs(c.getTime() - d.getTime()));
                Date e = new Date();
                //transactionHistoryExtRepository.saveAndFlush(transaction);
                Date f = new Date();
                System.out.println("Query Time: " + Math.abs(e.getTime() - f.getTime()));
                //Add to list
                transactions.add(transaction);
            }
            //Save & Update all records
            transactionHistoryExtRepository.saveAll(transactions);
            offset++;
        } while ((long) offset * bulkSize < max);
```

The query

```
List<TransactionHistoryExtEntity> findTopByReferenceNumberAndTransactionDateAndAmountOrderByTransactionDateDesc(
            String referenceNo, Date transactionDate, BigDecimal amount);
```

I am a bit new with this spring boot stuff. I am trying to insert/update 50k-100k of records into the table. Running 10k seems fast enough however as the size increases the time it takes for the query part in the inner for loop increases. For a record of 50k with 10k bulksize, the first 10k took about 80 seconds to complete (the entire inner iteration), followed by 472 seconds for the next 10k while the last 10k took 1k+ seconds to process. Can anyone explain what is causing the issue? Also, I cleared my table before executing this, meaning it is empty when I run this.

As a result, I tried different bulksize such as 30k and 50k. At 30k bulksize, which means it will be 2 outer loops, it completes everything at about 38mins, 50k bulksize at about 33 mins whereas 10k at an hour for 50k records. But this would defeat the purpose of having pagination at the start.

So I noticed that the avg time to query spiked after saveAll method. I am not too sure if it is due to the saveAll or the size of the records. Without the inner loop query part, the entire process just takes about 1 mins to complete.

Does anyone have any idea regarding the issue and how I can increase the performance?

Comment: Dealing with massive data in hibernate is not easy. First of all, since you do `transactionHistoryExtRepository.saveAndFlush(transaction)` inside the inner loop, why do you do it again in the outer loop. The second is probably useless but also harmless on a performance point of view. In fact, as soon as you save a `transaction` it enters the 1st level cache of hibernate and the size of this cache tends to slow the process. In my experience, clearing the entity manager never allowed to recover normal performances. The only way to make it work was to restart a new entity manager.

Comment: Don't use `saveAndFlush` use `save` after each x iteratons call `flush` and `clear` on the entitymanager. Don't store in a list (why save all if you already saved all he single elements?). Don't use pagination, use a stream (with the flush and clear).

Comment: Since you do a select query after the save, the flush will be triggered automatically by hibernate.

Comment: I used saveAll in my actual code. Forgot to comment out the saveAndFlush which I used for testing purposes.

Comment: @M.Deinum how do I clear the entityManager?  I am using TransactionHistoryExtRepository which extends the JpaRepo. I read that entityManager.clear() can help increase the speed. How do I clear it in my case?

Comment: Just inject it into your class like other dependencies.

Comment: ANother issue you have, and which is really a performance killer, is you have a 1+N select problem. You query something, iterate over it and for each element retrieve something else. Depending on what it eventually does you are probably better of doing a single query to retrieve the stuff you need, or write an update statement to link the history instead of retrieve eveything, link in code and do an update.

Comment: `EntityManager.clear()` is the way to clear the entity manager, supposibly improving performances but in my experience it was not enough. The only way that worked was to recreate the entityManager but that implies (not only to flush but) to commit the db-transaction. This means that you loose the hability to rollback your entire process.